# Issue with Installing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an issue with the installation of Tensorflow

I just completed installing Tensorflow with

`$ pip install --user --upgrade tensorflow`

and these are the last lines I get after this installation

``````
Successfully built absl-py gast
Installing collected packages: wheel, six, grpcio, absl-py, numpy, gast, astor, tensorflow, h5py, werkzeug, se                           tuptools
Successfully installed absl-py-0.7.1 astor-0.8.0 gast-0.2.2 grpcio-1.21.1 h5py-2.9.0 numpy-1.16.4 setuptools-4                           1.0.1 six-1.12.0 tensorflow-1.13.1 werkzeug-0.15.4 wheel-0.33.4  `````
``````

and then when I enter the following command:

`$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

I do get a bunch of `requirement already up-to-date` as per the below .

```
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-p                           ackages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packag                           es (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: gast>=0.2.0 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages                            (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages                            (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from                            tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (fro                           m tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\users\xxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-package                           s (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflo                           w)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\xxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages                            (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from                            tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\xxxx\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packag                           es (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf>=3.6.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow                           )
```

Which I interpret as everything is installed and upgraded ( am I wrong here ? )

Now my issue is that when I try to import Tensorflow let say in Jupyter notebook , I get the following error message

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Any idea what could be the reason and what i need to change to get tensorflow up and running ?

Thanks guys in advance for any help with the above issue .

Comment: Are you using Anaconda and what is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by downgrading tensorflow to version 2.0 using this command:

> pip install tensorflow==2.0

and then use like this :

> from tensorflow.keras.applications import vgg19
>   from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

I hope it helps.